# Hide tab bar containerview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uicontainerview

I have a tab bar controller and in one of my views I want that tab bar hidden. I selected `BottomBar - none` in interface but when my view appears there is still a white outline at the bottom of this view. I have a container view at the bottom of this view that I want extended all the way to the bottom of the screen. There is also a navigation controller embedded after the tab bar going into this view. Not sure if that makes a difference. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance. There are some photos of what I'm talking about below.

[image: view]
[image: storyboard1]

Answer (score 1):

try on viewDidLoad

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: I think `viewWillAppear:` would be better. Otherwise, you will see this transition.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that didn't work. Do you think there is a problem with it being embedded in a nav bar? The set up goes TabBar -> NavBar -> V1 -> VIEW IN QUESTION WITH CONTAINER VIEW.

Comment: can you try it on V1? also in viewWillAppear

Comment: yeah, still the same thing.